# Evaluate performance values following probability distributions in MCDM

Tags: probability-distributions, multicriteria-decision-analysis, uncertainty, statistics

If I have MCDM problems with performance values as "random variables", for instance, one value for object $A$ follows $\mathcal{N}(60,100)$ and the same criterion value for object $B$ follows $\mathcal{N}(40,200)$. Is there any vigorous way to investigate the difference between those two values? Or is this simply a statistics problem while in a MCDM setting? Like in TOPSIS, how can I construct a reasonable "distance" to calculate the final closeness coefficient?

For uncertainty in MCDM, I suppose related topics include fuzzy MCDM and grey MCDM, but herein I'm faced with a probability setting.